# How to link to /.well-known/assetlinks.json in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twa

I am not a ruby coder, In my ruby on rails app I need to link to

```
 /.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

I placed the file in `/public/.well-known` directory. But I can't link to

```
www.mydomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Usually files are linked in fingerprinted way in my website, so I think I need to fingerprint `assetlinks.json`.

How to do it with public folder. In my html.erb file I link files like

```
<%= image_path 'jum-mob.jpg'%>, <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

etc. How to do it for assetlinks.json. If I fingerprint it, will it work for trusted web activity app?

Edit: I can link to

```
https://www.example.com/public/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

but not to

```
https://www.exaple.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

My `config/routs.rb` have `root to: "home#index"`.

Comment: Some help please...

Comment: Hey man, I facing with same thing. Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a while after your question, but if anyone is interested with an answer:

in routes.rb :

```
get '/.well-known/assetlinks.json' => "static#assetlinks", :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

in static_controller.rb

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :assetlinks #might be optionnal for your app

  def assetlinks
  end
end
```

then in views/static/assetlinks.json.erb

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.your_app.something",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "AE:B4......:D4"
    ]
  }
}]
```

Then you can test if it's working :
https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator